ViroBox onClick causes exception thrown - unrecognized selector sent to instance
I have the following code:
import {
  ViroBox,
  ViroARScene,
  ViroARSceneNavigator,
} from "@reactvision/react-viro";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";

const HelloWorldSceneAR = () => {
  return (
    <ViroARScene>
           <ViroBox onClick={()=>{console.log("Clicked")}} />
    </ViroARScene>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <ViroARSceneNavigator
      autofocus={true}
      initialScene={{
        scene: HelloWorldSceneAR,
      }}
      style={styles.f1}
    />
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  f1: { flex: 1 }
});



This code runs fine on Android devices.  But on iOS devices, I get the error:
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[VRTBox setOnClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111595d00

If I delete the onClick, then the error message on iOS devices disappear.  However, this means I lose the ability to tap on the ViroBox on iOS devices.
I also tried this:
   <ViroARScene>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log("Clicked")}}>
           <ViroBox />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </ViroARScene>

But this gave the error
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[RCTView setSuperview:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1115868e0

I also tried this:
    <ViroARScene>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{console.log("Clicked")}}>
           <ViroBox />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </ViroARScene>

But that gave this error:
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[VRTBox setOnClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111595d10

What am I doing wrong?

And this is my package.json
{       
  "name": "ViroStarterKit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },            
  "dependencies": {
    "@reactvision/react-viro": "^2.41.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.3"
  },    
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.20",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.4",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },      
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }           
}   


Other notes...I've tried using @reactvision/react-viro version 2.41.3, 2.41.4, 2.41.5 and 2.41.6, but they all encounter this problem.
